# ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()- Python-Flask-SocketIo-Threading

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-multithreading, wsgi, flask-socketio

I have a web application using the python flask module which has flask_socketio implementation for communication between server and client. An API in the application will be invoked by the client, the method will invoke a function in a thread and returns the response. The thread function will make multiple HTTP requests and it gets socket messages as well.

After a few hours/few executions, I'm the below error

> (10160) wsgi exited, is_accepting=True
> Exception in thread Thread-1:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
> self.run()
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio_*init**.py", line 578, in run_server
> log_output=log_output, **kwargs)
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\wsgi.py", line 990, in server
> client_socket, client_addr = sock.accept()
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 230, in accept
> self._trampoline(fd, read=True, timeout=self.gettimeout(), timeout_exc=_timeout_exc)
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\greenio\base.py", line 210, in _trampoline
> mark_as_closed=self.*mark_as_closed)
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs_*init**.py", line 159, in trampoline
> return hub.switch()
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\hub.py", line 298, in switch
> return self.greenlet.switch()
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\hub.py", line 350, in run
> self.wait(sleep_time)
> File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\eventlet\hubs\selects.py", line 42, in wait
> r, w, er = select.select(reader_fds, writer_fds, all_fds, seconds)
> ValueError: too many file descriptors in select()

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'
CORS(app)
socketIo = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")
app.debug = True
app.host = '0.0.0.0'


@socketIo.on("data")
def handleMessage(msg):
    socketIo.emit('data', msg)
    return None


@socketIo.on("connect")
def handleMessage():
    print('connect')
    return None


def sendMessage(msg):
    print('inside send message')
    socketIo.emit(('message', 'sending message from rest'))
    return None


@socketIo.on('disconnect')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')
    return None

app.register_blueprint(execution_blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketIo.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

Thread:

```
class Compute(Thread):
    def __init__(self, data):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.data = data

    def run(self)
        execution(self.data)


def start_thread(data):
    thread_a = Compute(data)
    thread_a.start()
    return "Process Started in Background"
```